# What should I look for when setting up an outpost?

Tags: state-of-decay

What should I look for when setting up an outpost in *State of Decay*? What buildings are best and what are all of the benefits (other than a storage locker)?

An outpost is a building used as a satellite by the survivors, not part of the main base.

Comment: You are asking for a catalog which is not handled by Arqade or any StackExchange site. Could you try to state a more specific question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The outposts and the safezones around them provide a lot of benefits:

- Supply locker (as you already know)
- Increase chance of missing survivors coming home by themselves (15% for the Warehouse outpost, still need to check the others and if the bonuses stack)
- Prevent zombies from spawning inside the safezones. Thus, a good place to place them is on street corners or areas with lots of buildings.
- Safezones can be armed with explosives, which is the safest and most cost effective way of killing Zombie Hordes. Thus, another good locations for outposts is on the main roads leading to your Safehouse. Position them properly and you can cover a good portion of your base's perimeter.
- Last but not least, when you have fully searched the building and found supplies (food, medicine, construction material) but do not loot them, and establish it as an outpost, the outpost will double as a Resource Cache, i.e one the unlooted supplies will regenerate and reduce your daily consumption.

Regarding "What buildings are best for outpost?" question, in most cases they are buildings that have at least one Construction Material, to reduce your daily Material consumption. Construction Material is used in a lot of things and is constantly in short supply. All other resources become abundant from mid-game.

For more information, you can see the [Outposts](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Outposts) page on SoD Wiki.

Answer (score 4):

You want them to do 2 things, cover your base, number usually depends on which base you pick, and to cover the town/area nearby to keep zombies from spawning and to wipe out hordes, so near intersections and roads, and large groups of buildings are great.

Depending on the number of outposts you can make, you always want 1 outpost as your roaming outpost. Once you loot the areas, you move 1 outpost into new areas to set up a nice little safe zone where you can loot and drop off supplies from the new looted area.

If you leave 1 resource in an outpost you can do a few things. I think fuel and medicine still don't work, but food, materials and ammo do. Keep 1 of those in the outpost. Set up the outpost THEN take the resource, this way you get it plus get the outpost reduction boost. If the outpost is near your base, you can do THREE things. Call a scavenger on radio, then set up the outpost, then take the resource. This way you'll gain 3 benefits for the price of 1.

You can also place outposts at areas that you might see have lots of rescue missions, survivors needing help, etc. If you see a place that always calls you to rescue survivors and is far away, and is a pain to get to, great place for an outpost to lessen the headache. Usually its nice to have such missions happen near your base instead of far away, if it happens near you can do it much much quicker and have much better chance for nothing bad happening.

Answer (score 2):

The facilities mentioned are worth considering to balance your outposts since they are limited in number. However, spacing is also a major consideration. Place all, or at least three of your outposts within a few blocks around a home base in an "urban" area and it will become virtually safe to pillage with minimal infestations and hordes. 
On the other hand, having outlying outposts between your home base and a distant area you are Scaveging in can also be helpful.
Since you can abandon ad set up new outposts, you can juggle them to a degree, but don't waste too much influence points on that!

Answer (score 1):

Look for  outposts that cover as many roads as possible, for taking out hordes with traps.

If you're sick of having to constantly stop what you're doing and go "horde killing", note the areas hordes tend to travel to and make an outpost covering those roads.

I have mine at 3 way road junctions with traps set and I rarely have to hunt hordes down now, makes it a lot easier to handle when you have a lot going on.

Comment: sorry about the formatting fredley, not used to having to use code in answer posts. Don't know why hitting return to make a new line wasn't good enough for the good people who made this site but whatever, it's not an insurmountable problem.

Comment: Sites on the StackExchange network use [Markdown](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for formatting. It's a simple way to make text pretty with minimal syntax. It is designed to be readable even without any processing, hence the requirement for two linebreaks to make a new paragraph.